# Put different subclasses from the same base class into a list C#

Tags: c#, .net, subclass, superclass

I want to add different sub classes which extends from the same base class into a List.

So this is the base class:

```
public class InteractionRequirement {
        protected int requirementNumber;

        public int RequirementNumber{
            get{ return requirementNumber;}
            set{ requirementNumber = value;}
        }
    }
```

And these are the subclasses:

```
public class ObjectInteraction : InteractionRequirement {
    protected string objectName;
    --getter and setter here--
}
public class CharacterInteraction: InteractionRequirement {
    protected string characterName;
    --getter and setter here--
}
public class AssetInteraction: InteractionRequirement {
   protected string assetName;
   --getter and setter here--
}
```

And I added them in one list:

```
List<InteractionRequirement> interactionRequirements = new List<InteractionRequirement>();
ObjectInteraction objectInteraction = new ObjectInteraction();
CharacterInteraction characterInteraction = new CharacterInteraction();
AssetInteraction assetInteraction = new AssetInteraction();

interactionRequirements.Add(objectInteraction);
interactionRequirements.Add(characterInteraction);
interactionRequirements.Add(assetInteraction);
```

But I can't seem to retrieve attribute values from the sub classes, there's an error.

```
string oName = interactionRequirement[0].ObjectName;
string cName = interactionRequirement[1].CharacterName;
string aName = interactionRequirement[2].AssetName;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `interactionRequirements` collection is of type `InteractionRequirement` not of the derived type (ObjectInteraction, CharacterIteraction or AssetInteraction).

Therefore, you'll need a cast.

```
string oName = ((ObjectInteraction)interactionRequirement[0]).ObjectName;
```

You can also use `as` and check if the cast was successful.

```
var objectInteraction = interactionRequirement[0] as ObjectInteraction;

if (objectInteraction != null) 
{
   string oName = objectInteraction.ObjectName;
}
```

http://ideone.com/4giIL4

As an additional note, you may need to change the protection level of `ObjectName` to `public` so you can access it in the appropriate context (Outside of the class and derived classes).

Comment: Its worth noting to the op that there isn't anyway to guarrantee that `element[0]` will always be an `ObjectInteraction` since you can remove and insert elements... so even though this would fix the error its not a long term solution (base class the name or make a `GetName` method)

Comment: @mattytommo - trying to keep up with you m8! ;)